# Does Docusign provide log of changes or an API to view edits during signing?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

If I have a TextField that is editable and the signer changes their Title while e-signing, is there a manner in which to monitor TextField edits?  Currently I am using the `EnvelopesApi.list_audit_events` to monitor events. In this case, all I can view is that the signer either 'opened', 'viewed', or 'signed' the envelope.  Although that is valuable information, I would also like to know which TextFields the signer edited and what the new values are? Did the signer change their email, title, name, etc? In this particular case I am using TextFields to display email, title, name, etc...

Does the Docusign API provide an avenue for fetching this information? If so, would you please provide a snippet demonstrating how to fetch this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do this by comparing the value that was in these fields before signing to the value you obtain from the envelope after singing.
There's no built-in event that will give you these changes as far as I'm aware, but it can be done using code.
I'm assuming here that what you're doing is setting the values of some text tabs and then want to know if the signer modified them or not. So, yes, you can do that.

Comment: How can I fetch the envelope?  Is there a method in the EnvelopesApi class that performs this?  @InbarGazit

Comment: This is how to do this in Java:
EnvelopesApi.GetEnvelopeOptions options = envelopesApi.new GetEnvelopeOptions();
options.setInclude("documents,recipients");
Envelope env = envelopesApi.getEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId, options);

Comment: I apologize because I should have mentioned that I am using the Python SDK . The Python SDK does not provide a congruent method for `GetEnvelopeOptions`.  Within the EnvelopesApi the `get_envelope` method does allow `kwargs` but nothing related to `documents` or `recipients`.  The `get_envelope` method only provides the status of the envelope in Python SDK. Do you have a proposed workaround for this issue? @InbarGazit

Comment: Python code:
env = envelopes_api.getEnvelope(account_id, envelope_id, include = 'documents,recipients')